# Have trouble on defining object in javascript file

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I'm making a project on asp.net core mvc, and there i have an issue in javascript file. There i have an object named as 'parsedJson' which contains several parameters (like 'status'). And when i run the project i have this issue [image].I decribed parsedJson in function like this

```
function checkStatus(myID) {
    $.ajax(
        {
            url: '/MemoryGame/checkStatus',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { 'ID': myID },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (response) {
                var parsedJson = response;
                if (parsedJson.ifQuit == "True") {
                    OpponentQuit(parsedJson.myID);
                }
                else {
                    else if (parsedJson.status == "Won") {
                        FunctionName(parsedJson);
                    }
                    else if (parsedJson.status == "Lost") {
                        FunctionName(parsedJson);
                    }
                    else if (parsedJson.status == "Tie") {
                        FunctionName(parsedJson);
                    }
                }
            },
            error: function (errorThrown) {
                console.log(errorThrown);
                ConnectionChanged();
            }
        });
}

function FunctionName(parsedJson)
{  
   ...
    if (parsedJson.status == "Won") {
        YouWon(parsedJson.myID);
    }
    else if (parsedJson.status == "Lost") {
        YouLost(parsedJson.myID);
    }
    else if (parsedJson.status == "Tie") {
        GameTied(parsedJson.myID);
    }
}
```

Btw parsedJson file is not empty, and status has its own values every running time.
Can anyone suggest me right way of defining an object in function?

Comment: Please post your code as text, not as an image, and include the part of the code where `parsedJson` is defined.

Comment: i added them in post

Comment: I tested based on the existing code ,but there is no error .What's the complete code of your js file?

Comment: @XueliChen i couldn't understand it too, because this code works on another file of this project

Answer (score -1):

I think Javascript objects are usually defined as:

```
let newObject = {
    property1: 'a string',
    property2: 3,
    property3: true
}
```

Those properties can then be referenced as newObject.property1, newObject.property2, etc.

The W3Schools page on Javascript objects is [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp)

Comment: i think i asked question wrong. I need define an object as function parameter